# Get distribution of consecutive occurrences of some target value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I am given the following list

`x = ['A','A','B','A','A','A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A']`

What would be the best and most efficient way to generate the following output

```
# key = number of consecutives
# val = number of occurrences
>>> func(x, 'A')
{2:2, 3:1}

>>> func(x, 'B')
{1:1}

>>> func(x, 'C')
{2:1}
```

We may assume that the list is all strings. Any ideas?

Comment: While I disagree with 'unclear' vote, you should provide your own attempt.

Comment: Above all it is opinion based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work, making use of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter

def func(lst, elmnt):
    return Counter(len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(lst) if k == elmnt)

>>> func(x, 'A')
Counter({2: 1, 3: 1})
```

While this will probably not be bested for single calls, you would be better off building an intermediate data structure that collects counts for groups of all different elements in a single go-around so that subsequent calls for individual elements won't have to iterate the entire list again:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def func(lst):
    c = Counter((k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(lst))
    d = defaultdict(dict)
    for (k, length), count in c.items():
        d[k][length] = count
    return d.get

>>> f = func(x)  # builds intermediate structure (O(N)), returns function to query it
>>> f('A')  # these calls are now all O(1)
{2: 1, 3: 1}
>>> f('B')
{1: 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def f(x, t):
    n = 0
    result = defaultdict(int)
    for c in x:
        if c == t:
            n += 1
        else:
            result[n] += 1
            n = 0
    result[n] += 1
    del result[0]
    return result
```

whether it is the best is totally opinion based. IMO it is the best because I wrote it and, in my own opinion, I am the best.

On a more objective note: @schwobaseggl 's solution is more concise but a quick `%timeit` experiment tells me mine is 5x faster on your example and possibly a lot more on other examples... So 'best' really depends on what you value most. (even 'efficient' is rather vague: are you considering processing time, memory usage, .. ?)